# How to show my window along with the QToolTip widget?

Tags: qt, qtooltip

I would like to show my window along with, on the side of `QToolTip`, when it is shown on request with `QToolTip::showText()`.

QToolTip class has the hideText method, but it also hides by itself, and there doesn't seem to be a signal to tell the app when tooltip is shown/hidden.

Is there a way to catch a moment when it is displayed and a moment when it is hidden, to know the QToolTip widget object, and to show my window (some graph) along with it?

Comment: Explicate better Please

Comment: Are you asking for a signal that fires when [isVisible()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#isVisible) changes?

Comment: I am asking for a signal that will be called when isVisible() changes, plus for a way to know the bounding box of QToolTip.